# Firefox Addon MySql connection

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, firefox-addon, browser-addons

I would like to connect a MySql database which is hosted at an online hosting service.
I would like to use the WebExtensions APIs (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions). How can I program this with JavaScript?

Thank you in advance for your replies!

Best wishes
Fabs

Comment: read [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/ndbapi/en/ndb-nodejs-examples-requirements.html) and see how likely you can make it work

Comment: It better to create an (rest) API for exporting the functionality you want and access it through that. Putting your username and password of your database to your JS code is not a good practise.

Answer (score 0):

You would host this on a server, and then navigate to URLs (with ajax) and handle that data. This is called a REST API.